# Peek iterator inside `for` loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to peek at the char in-front of my current location whilst iterating over a `&str`.

```rust
let myStr = "12345";
let mut iter = myStr.chars().peekable();
for c in iter {
    let current: char = c;
    let next: char = *iter.peek().unwrap_or(&'∅');
}
```

I will be passing this char into a method down the line. However, even this MRE produces a borrow after move error that I'm not sure how to get past.

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `iter`
   --> src/lib.rs:7:27
    |
4   |     let mut iter = myStr.chars().peekable();
    |         -------- move occurs because `iter` has type `Peekable<Chars<'_>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
5   |     for c in iter {
    |              ---- `iter` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
6   |         let current: char = c;
7   |         let next: char = *iter.peek().unwrap_or(&'∅');
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `iter`
   --> /home/james/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:267:18
    |
267 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
```

Any idea what's going on here? I've tried various combinations of referencing and dereferencing but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iterator is moved into the `for` loop. You cannot manually manipulate an iterator inside a `for` loop. However, the `for` loop can be replaced by `while let`:

```rust
while let Some(c) = iter.next() {
    let current: char = c;
    let next: char = *iter.peek().unwrap_or(&'∅');
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b3fdf433e598d6fc4a6c48cf002cebb).

Answer (score 3):

If you can work with slices, it will get much easier with `windows()`:

```
let slice = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
let iter = slice.windows(2);
for arr in iter {
    let current = arr[0];
    let next = arr[1];
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f982ee7e3b6da49aba3ceabce415e15a)